# How can I call a shell function from a Perl script?

Tags: perl, shell

Say, I have a shell script like this:

### utils.sh

```
function getDir
{
    echo "DirName"
}
```

I want to use that function from a Perl script:

### test.pl

```
`source utils.sh`;

my $dir_name = `getDir`;

print $dir_name;
```

But this is not working. How I can get this done? Essentially I need to get the return value from a shell function to a Perl script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to call that function in the same shell that sources `utils.sh`, so:

```
my $dir_name = `source utils.sh; getDir`;
chomp($dir_name);
print $dir_name, "\n";
```